# Type a function with a parameter of any type except if it has a member that is not a string

Tags: typescript

I need a function to take an argument with these restrictions:

1. Can be anything (primitives, objects, arrays, ...) as long as it **does not** have a member called `x`.
2. If it **does** have a member called `x` it has to be of type `string`.

**How can type a function like that?**

```
declare function foo<T /* extends ??? */ >(arg: T): boolean
```

Using conditional types I get something working but then another problem arises.

```
type Constrained<T> = 'x' extends keyof T
    ? (T extends { x: string } ? T : never)
    : T;

declare function foo<T>(a: Constrained<T>): boolean;
```

Basically, `Constraint<T>` resolves to `never` if `T` have a member called `x` that is not of type `string` or resolves to `T` otherwise. Then, any call to `foo` with an "invalid" object will be rejected since nothing can be assigned to `never` (except `never` itself).

It works pretty well... until I have something like this

```
class SomeClass<U /* extends ??? */> {
    prop!: U;

    method() {
        // Fails :(
        // How to restrict U to allow this call?
        foo(this.prop); // <-- Error: Argument of type 'U' is not
                        //            assignable to parameter of
                        //            type 'Constrained<U>'.
    }
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Constrained%3CT%3E%20%3D%20'x'%20extends%20keyof%20T%0A%20%20%20%20%3F%20(T%20extends%20%7B%20x%3A%20string%20%7D%20%3F%20T%20%3A%20never)%0A%20%20%20%20%3A%20T%3B%0A%0Adeclare%20function%20foo%3CT%3E(a%3A%20Constrained%3CT%3E)%3A%20boolean%3B%0A%0A%0Adeclare%20const%20a%3A%20%7B%20x%3A%20string%20%7D%3B%0Adeclare%20const%20b%3A%20%7B%20a%3A%20boolean%20%7D%3B%0Adeclare%20const%20c%3A%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20These%20are%20OK%20as%20expected%0Afoo(a)%3B%0Afoo(b)%3B%0Afoo(c)%3B%0Afoo(1)%3B%0Afoo(%5B%7B%7D%2C%20true%5D)%3B%0A%0Adeclare%20const%20x%3A%20%7B%20x%3A%20number%20%7D%3B%0A%0Afoo(x)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%3C--%20Fail%20as%20expected%2C%20x%20is%20type%20%7B%20x%3A%20number%20%7D%0A%0Aclass%20SomeClass%3CU%20%2F*%20extends%20%3F%3F%3F%20*%2F%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20prop!%3A%20U%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20method()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Fails%20%3A(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20How%20to%20restrict%20U%20to%20allow%20this%20call%3F%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20foo(this.prop)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

Comment: Could you just declare `U extends Constrained<U>`?

Comment: @MattMcCutchen Nope, Error: Type parameter 'U' has a circular constraint. I also tried some similar constraints but one simply cannot use the whole type `U` to constraint itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd be inclined to stay away from complex constraints like this unless you really need it.  My recommendation is to build up the type you're talking about from more primitive pieces, like this:

```
type Unknown = string | number | boolean | symbol | null | void | object;
type Constraint = Exclude<Unknown, object> | { [k: string]: unknown, x?: string };
```

That `Constraint` is just a plain old union, and it more or less represents everything except an object with a non-`string` value for the `x` key.  Is it perfect?  Maybe not, but it is a lot easier to deal with:

```
declare function foo<T extends Constraint>(a: T): boolean;
class SomeClass<T extends Constraint> { /* ... */ };

foo(undefined); // okay
foo(null); // okay
foo("string"); // okay
foo(123); // okay
foo([]); // okay
foo([123]); // okay
foo([123, { x: "string" }]); // okay
foo(() => 123); // okay
foo({}); // okay
foo({ a: 123 }); // okay
foo({ a: 123, x: 123 }); // error
foo({ a: 123, x: { y: 123 } }); // error
foo(Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : { a: 123, x: "string" }); // okay
```

And you have no problem inside `SomeClass` anymore:

```
class SomeClass<T extends Constraint> {
  prop!: T;
  method() {
    foo(this.prop); // easy-peasy
  }
}
```

---

---

If you find yourself in dire need of a circular or self-referential constraint, it is possible to placate the compiler, but this tends to be a trial-and-error thing for me with many pitfalls along the way.  Let's start with your type function:

```
type Constrained<T> = 'x' extends keyof T
  ? (T extends { x: string } ? T : never)
  : T;
```

Your initial `foo` definition seems to work, but only via some possibly-risky [type inference](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3117-type-inference):

```
declare function foo<T>(a: Constrained<T>): boolean;
```

How does the compiler know what `T` is given that `a` is of type `Constrained<T>`?  It has to treat `Constrained<T>` as an inference site for `T`, by seeing through the conditional type in some way.  I *guess* the compiler sees that `Constrained<T>` is assignable to `never | T`, which is `T`, so it infers that `T` is the same type as `a`.   Anyway, that's fine.

---

A more "officially supported" way to do this kind of thing is to make `a` of type `T & Constrained<T>`, since intersections are [known to serve as inference sites](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21316#issuecomment-372861808).  This is really the same as what you put but would make me sleep more soundly at night:

```
declare function foo<T>(a: T & Constrained<T>): boolean;
```

---

As for the class, the thing you really *want* to do gives you a circular constraint error:

```
class SomeClass<T extends Constrained<T>> { /* ... * / } // error!
// Type parameter 'T' has a circular constraint.
```

This can be worked around by adding some dummy type parameters and using a conditional type whose evaluation is deferred until `SomeClass` is instantiated concretely:

```
class SomeClass<T extends (U extends any ? Constrained<T> : unknown), U = any> { /* ... * / }

declare const ok: SomeClass<{ a: string }>; // okay
declare const alsoOk: SomeClass<{ x: string }>; // okay
declare const notOk: SomeClass<{ x: number }>; // error, number not a string
```

The compiler doesn't notice the circularity anymore, but it's still there.

The implementation of the class will still give you errors, precisely because you're delaying the compiler's inspection of the otherwise circular constraint, so it doesn't know what you're doing will be safe:

```
class SomeClass<T extends (U extends any ? Constrained<T> : unknown), U = any> {
  prop!: T;
  method() {
    foo(this.prop); // still error
  }
}
```

One way to handle that is to make `prop` of type `Constrained<T>` instead of `T`:

```
class SomeClass<T extends (U extends any ? Constrained<T> : unknown), U = any> {
  prop!: Constrained<T>;
  method() {
    foo(this.prop); // okay now
  }
}
```

But you will still likely run into other such issues elsewhere, and you might eventually have to just go with [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to silence the errors:

```
class SomeClass<T extends (U extends any ? Constrained<T> : unknown), U = any> {
  prop!: T;
  method() {
    foo(this.prop as Constrained<T>); // I know what I'm doing!
  }
}
```

Anyway, you can see what a mess this is.  That's why I still recommend the initial plain-old-union solution.

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the elaborated answer. I think you missed the restriction backwards: If the object has a member `x` it **has to be** of type `string`, so the one you marked as `foo({a: 123, x: "string"}); // error` is the only one should work. The same here `type Constrained<T> = T extends { x: string } ? never : T`.

Comment: Hey, yeah I got it backwards.  I'll fix it.

Comment: BTW The reason I was trying something like this is because `foo` needs to call a function in its argument only if it exists. That is easy to do at runtime, but the function needs a particular signature to work and a wrong function should be catch at compile time. If the argument does not have such a function it goes another branch.